# How to change the camera target without having that target automatically centered on the screen

Tags: babylonjs

Here is a playground to illustrate my problem: https://playground.babylonjs.com/#V181I2#34

On my scene I’m trying to replicate the camera’s behavior we have with paraview.

- left drag → rotation around some point. OK
- right drag → panning of the camera, but without changing the rotation center. I managed to do that using camera.targetScreenOffset thanks to a Playground I found here (https://playground.babylonjs.com/#EBPQH9#43 → many thanks to the author !)
- Now on double click (for example) on a mesh, I would like to change the center of rotation to the center of the mesh, but again without having the targeted mesh centered on the screen, without having the current view changed the slightest.

I’ve been searching a lot how to do that without success.
From my understanding, in order for the target mesh not to be automatically centered:

- modifying the camera position is useless. It would only change the perspective.
- setting the right values for the targetScreenOffset would work. But I don’t know how to determine them. I’ve been looking for the right way to project a distance computed in the world coordinate system (between 2 successive camera targets) to coordinates for the targetScreenOffset property, without success. I don’t even understand the units used by that property.
- there must be some other ways ?

Right now I don’t feel qualified enough to write the camera’s behavior from scratch.

Would anyone be able to help me or point me in the right direction?